# Replacing / before last segment with #

Tags: php, expressionengine

I am needing to change the url of a search result
from: http://www.example.com/this/page/section
to: http://www.example.com/this/page#section

The page url is being returned from EEs `{page_url}` tag. I also have access to the last segment through EE using `{url_title}`. I've tried using explode and then imploding but haven't succeeded. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not care about URL not containing a "/":

```
$url[strrpos($url,'/')]='#';
```

Comment: I want to preserve the url entirely just replacing the / before the last segment with #. I believe that I have achieved what I need. `$fixed_url = str_replace('/'.$last_segment,'#'.$last_segment,$page_url);`

Comment: Sure. My example is still valid. Just make a copy of it first.. ( `$fixed_url=$page_url='{page_url}'; $fixed_url[strrpos($fixed_url,'/')]='#'; `)